# Генерация дорог по линиям

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl

Суть в том, что для 3D движка дороги должны генерироваться по определенным координатам(а не как отдельные меши из вершин)

Но взяв в качестве линии ломаную линию(вдоль которой генерируется дорога), то в по ее координатам дорога генерируется грубо, и в местах, где она должна плавно поворачивать, разумеется, такого не происходит. Как это решить? Стоит использовать в качестве исходных данные те же ломаные линии, а не кривые?

Comment: Не совсем то – но по той же теме [вопрос на Тостере](https://toster.ru/q/66044) про построение дорог.

Comment: линия, по контексту это имеется ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сглаживать [сплайнами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD), или простой геометрией получать арки на поворотах:

[image: шайба едет по ломаной]

Есть разные типы сплайнов – [некоторые](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) и по трём точкам сделают плавный поворот, а больше точек понадобится, наоборот, для более острого поворота. Может, [кубический сплайн](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) более всего подходит?

Нашёл ещё статью (на англ.) [про дороги в играх](http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/curved-paths/).

Comment: а как на счет случая, когда нужен плавный продолжительный поворот? Просто увеличить количество вершин?

Comment: спасибо за источники, пока разбираюсь, но пока что под вопросом то, какие должны быть отличительные характеристики тех линий, где нужны плавные повороты, и той, где нужен резкий поворот, например тот же на 90 градусов

Comment: кажется, квадратичные кривые Безье именно то, что нужно